# What does the P stand for in the Type column?

Tags: adnd-2e

I'm hoping someone can help me clarify what all the columns mean.

[image: Part of a weapon list from 2nd Edition D&D]

Take Barbed Dart, for example.

The 1sp is obviously to indicate that it costs 1 silver piece per dart.

The 2 indicates that it has a weight of 2 pounds.

The rest I am not sure.

**The S says that it is a small item?**

**The 1d3 and 1d2, are they damage dice when used to attack small/medium and large enemy types? (respectively)**

**I'm not sure what the P means for the Type<sup>6</sup>**

Comment: Just a note : the superscript 6 most probably indicates a footnote and is not part of the column label, which is just "Type".

Comment: Does your copy not explain the footnotes? o.O

Comment: For both these questions, the text under Weapons in the equipment description section explains all the columns... p. 73 in my first printing.

Comment: The column headers are also out of alignment... "Weight" belongs with "(lb.)", "Speed" belongs with "Factor", and "Damage" belongs with "S-M / L"

Comment: That's a pirated PDF (I just checked; the PDF with that exact page break and broken headers is easily found). You would be much better off with a legal copy of the book that doesn't have broken tables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The 2 indicates that it has a weight of 2 pounds.

Actually, you missed the row. The blowgun weights 2 pounds. The dart has a weight of * which means 10 of them weight 1 pound. Just in case you wonder when it comes to other items, ** means this weights so little that you can carry an unlimited amount with you.

> The S says that it is a small item?

Correct.

> The 1d3 and 1d2, are they damage dice when used to attack small/medium and large enemy types? (respectively)

Correct.

> I'm not sure what the P means for the Type6 means

That the damage type is **P**iercing damage. Other weapons do **B**ludgeoning and/or **S**lashing damage. Note the dash when the weapon itself does not do damage, like a bow or sling. Only the ammunition is marked for damage type.

The column "factor" is a misprint in your table and actually reads "Speed Factor". That's the value that gets added to your initiative roll to determine who acts first in combat (See chapter 9: Combat, paragraph "Initiative"). The higher the number, the more cumbersome is the weapon and the more time is needed to hit someone with it. For example you can stab someone with a dagger real fast, while taking a swing with a twohanded sword takes time. The guy with the dagger is most likely going first in any round of combat.